# Avoid Django s3-urls stripping

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm trying to setup a mini django app to allow users to download files from s3.
I wrote a simple python function (using boto of course) to fetch the correct url but when i handle the url with django the url is stripped.

this is my urlfetcher:

```
def s3url(key):
    s3 = None
    try:
        s3 = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id=settings.access_id,aws_secret_access_key=settings.secret_key,is_secure=False)
    except boto.exception.S3ResponseError:
        print "[S3] unable to connect to s3!"
        return None
    url = s3.generate_url( settings.EXPIRES_IN, 'GET', bucket=settings.BUCKET, key=key)
    return url
```

and this is my django view

```
def gets3(request,key):
    url = aws.s3url(key)
    return HttpResponse(url)
```

when i try the view in the django shell i get the following:

```
>>> r = manager.s3_views.gets3('xxxxx/5/2014-03-10_08:37:39.274998-d3421964017734f96198c74d853eb2e7')
>>> print r
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

http://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/5/2014-03-10_08%3A37%3A39.274998-d3421964017734f96198c74d853eb2e7?Signature=FVWZPBnoOAOm5PuNOajQ3Ce5GrM%3D&Expires=1395310316&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI4QC5JE7YMBEITJA
```

that is right but when i use it withing django runserve i get only:

```
http://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/?Signature=PhR4IfGwKHsryp2fAllLPSc9Bds%3D&Expires=1395311016&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI4QC5JE7YMBEITJA
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the enigma...

The regex in the `urls.py` was wrong so it pass no parameters to the `gets3` function.
Hence, the function return a stripped URL :(